# Reduce a lazy sequence like a loop with a condition in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have an infinite lazy sequence that produce a "preamble" and a "pattern repetition", a simple example of this kind of sequence could be implemented in Clojure with:

```
(def infinite-lazy-sequence
  (lazy-cat [4] (cycle [1 2 3])))

=> (take 20 infinite-lazy-sequence)
(4 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1)
```

I would like to get a `set` of the elements forming this `infinite-lazy-sequence`, here is a way to implement it using `loop`:

```
(loop
  [[head & tail] infinite-lazy-sequence
   result #{}]
  (if (contains? result head)
    result
    (recur tail (conj result head))))

=> #{1 2 3 4}
```

Here is the question: is it possible to achieve the same result using `reduce`? And using `take-while`?

**Edit:**

*Benchmark results using clojure-1.5.1 and perforate-0.2.4*

proposed `loop-recur` implementation:

```
Case:  :loop-recur
Evaluation count : 60 in 60 samples of 1 calls.
             Execution time mean : 1.054975 sec
    Execution time std-deviation : 26.316442 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 1.026187 sec ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 1.125854 sec (97.5%)
```

@sw1nn `reduce-reduced` implementation:

```
Case:  :reduce-reduced
Evaluation count : 120 in 60 samples of 2 calls.
             Execution time mean : 875.091831 ms
    Execution time std-deviation : 19.745142 ms
   Execution time lower quantile : 850.871606 ms ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 921.947759 ms (97.5%)
```

Comment: So no element in your infinite sequence may occur twice before the repeated pattern starts repeating, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Unfortunately I don't know how long the preamble could be... Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clojure 1.5 added `reduced` to allow shortcircuiting reduces...

```
 (reduce (fn [a v] (if-not (a v) (conj a v) (reduced a))) 
         #{} 
         infinite-lazy-sequence)
 => #{1 2 3 4}
```

Comment: thanks @sw1nn, I have just benchmarked it with my target `infinite-lazy-sequence` and your reduce-reduced version seems also faster with Clojure 1.5.1