# Order a list of 2-tuple (x,y) into a sorted-map of sets in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to create a `sorted-map` of `sorted-set` with the function `list-of-xy->sorted-map-of-sets`:

```
(def in
  '([1 9] [1 8] [1 7]
     [2 1] [2 2] [2 3]
     [2 1] [2 2] [2 3]
     [2 1] [2 2] [2 3]))

(def out
  (into (sorted-map)
    {1 (sorted-set 9 8 7)
     2 (sorted-set 1 2 3)}))

(defn list-of-xy->sorted-map-of-sorted-sets [list-of-xy]
  "Take a list (or lazy-seq) of 2-tuple and return a sorted-map of sorted-sets"
  (reduce ????? list-of-xy))


; should return true
(= (list-of-xy->sorted-map-of-sorted-sets in) out)
```

So far I tried creating `out` in two steps:

```
(def int1
    (group-by #(first %) in))
;=> { 1 [[1 9] [1 8] [1 7]],
;     2 [[2 1] [2 2] [2 3] [2 1] [2 2] [2 3] [2 1] [2 2] [2 3]]}

(def int2
    (flatten
      (map
        #(let [[x xys] %]
           (list x (sorted-set (map last xys))))
        int1)))
;=> (1 #{7 8 9} 2 #{1 2 3}) ; <-- this is not a sorted-map (yet!)
```

What could be a better approach to transform `in --> out` having performance as a priority?

---

**BTW**

@Ankur answer accepted. It is the faster solution so far.

For my actual problem the `(update-in acc [x] conj y)` from the @amalloy solution (+1) opened the way to `reduced` via `get-in`. The reducing function I am using is:

```
(fn [a [x y]]
  (if-not (get-in a [x y])
    (update-in a [x] conj y)
    (reduced a)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(= out (into (sorted-map)
             (map (fn [[k v]]
                    [k (apply sorted-set (map second v))])
                  (group-by first in))))
```

Let me know if this pass your performance test :).

Comment: Eheh @Ankur, perf test passed! BTW I tried also changing `(map second v)` to `(map last v)` but your version is faster :D

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn list-of-xy->sorted-map-of-sorted-sets [list-of-xy]
  (let [conj (fnil conj (sorted-set))]
    (reduce (fn [acc [x y]]
              (update-in acc [x] conj y))
            (sorted-map)
            list-of-xy)))
```

Comment: Thanks @amalloy, I was wondering, is it possible with your solution to use "reduced" to short-circuiting the reduce with sequences like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625341/reduce-a-lazy-sequence-like-a-loop-with-a-condition-in-clojure ? Thanks

Comment: Sure, if you could somehow know that all the remaining list items are already in the set, you could stop early with `reduced`. Hard to imagine how you could know, though.